# how to not override the css file inside the blade php file

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

On my app.js on laravel I imported a library [bootstrap-vuejs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and it's using Bootstrap 4

**app.js**

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' //Bootstrap 4.3.1
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

and then on my blade php file i just called it

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}" defer></script>
```

my blade php file however has a Bootstrap version 3.3.7 because I'm using a laravel admin template [admin-lte](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE)

The issue is when I refresh the page the font / icons becomes bigger on page load.

[image]

but after the loading of the page eventually it will become like this

[image]

When I comment the bootstrap css on my app.js

```
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' (Bootstrap 4.3.1)
```

the problem is solved however i can't use the bootstrap css inside my vue component

Any idea how to fix this? because i think the bootstrap inside my app.js is overriding the boostrap 3.3.7 inside my blade php file.

Comment: You're using `Bootstrap-Vue`, which is built on top of `Boostrap4`, I'd suggest you get rid of/not use `admin-lte` and just do the admin panel yourself or you'll going to run into more of these compatibility issue down the road.  It's easy to write admin yourself in Bootstrap4.  Flex CSS, i.e. flex-row and flex-column in bs4 are pretty amazing, example -  https://laratt.niiknow.org code https://github.com/niiknow/laratt-api/blob/5117bfae1273b31f95af6aa99c51aae7fc413d2f/resources/js/components/MainLayout.vue#L40

Answer (score 0):

Try to import bootstrap css in your component where you need it.

In vue component, in style tag when it has the `scoped` attribute, the CSS will apply to the current component only.

```
<style scoped>
  @import 'path/to/bootstrap_verison.min.css';
  /*CSS styles*/
</style>
```